# How to write ruby method in js file

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to display in each cell of my calendar in js (fullcalendar) a ruby method “week_balance” where I have some informations but I can't. 
I write :

```
dayRender:function(cell, week_balance){
     $(cell).html(‘<span>’ + week_balance + ‘</span>’);
     },
```

It doesn't work, why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails framework, then it provides an option where you write ruby code in Js file.
For this, you need to change extension for js file to `.js.erb`
And then call ruby function is js method as,

```
dayRender:function(cell, week_balance){
   $(cell).html('<span>' + "<%= week_balance %>" + ‘</span>’);
},
```

make sure week_balance is accessible without any parent. Else make it class method and use it.